# How to implement hit counter with light box

Tags: php, lightbox, hitcounter

I want to count the number of hit on an image and also the image will show in a lightbox.
here is my code:

```
//image-show-content.php

<script>
function hitcounter(imgid)
{
//alert(imgid);
var imgid = imgid;
window.location.href ="image-show-content.php?img_id="+imgid;

}
</script>
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST['img_id']))
{
$show = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_image_gallery` WHERE image_id =".$_REQUEST['img_id']." ";
$result_show = mysql_query($show);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_show);

$new_click_count = $row['click_on_image'] +1;
$update_sql = "UPDATE `tbl_image_gallery` SET click_on_image =".$new_click_count." WHERE image_id=".$_REQUEST['img_id']."";
$result_sql= mysql_query($update_sql);

}
```

//image...

```
<a href="uploadedimage/gallery/big/<?=$val['gallery_image']?>" rel="lightbox[100,200]" title="<?=ucfirst($val['category_name'])?>"><img src="uploadedimage/gallery/thumble/<?=$val['gallery_image']?>" onclick="hitcounter('<?=$val[image_id]?>')"/></a>
?>
```

My problem is when I click on an image it return an error.
please help to solve it.Thanks in advance.Can you refer some other option to show light box and hit counter together.

Comment: You need to sort out your code formatting. Also, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Please *always* state what error you are getting exactly.

Comment: in this line "window.location.href ="image-show-content.php?img_id="+imgid;
" it return the value in a same page. that why light box will not show .

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, when your page loads. Lightbox javascript is already generating dynamic node for your  tag.

To achieve this you can try with onclick function into . In that function you should call AJAX call with your image id. It would be possible that your onclick function may call after lightbox call OR before lightbox call. So please debug for this too.

This would be only one way to achieve this as per my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Place your php code in one another file called, hit_image.php and place your code there,

```
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST['image_id']))
{
$show = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_image_gallery` WHERE image_id =".$_REQUEST['image_id']." ";
$result_show = mysql_query($show);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_show);

$new_click_count = $row['click_on_image'] +1;
$update_sql = "UPDATE `tbl_image_gallery` SET click_on_image =".$new_click_count." WHERE image_id=".$_REQUEST['image_id']."";
$result_sql= mysql_query($update_sql);

}
```

Now your HTML file should be like follow,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function counter(imageId)
    {   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","hit_image.php?image_id="+imageId,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<a onclick="counter(<?=$val[image_id]?>)" rel="lightbox[100,200]" title="<?=ucfirst($val['category_name'])?>"><img src="uploadedimage/gallery/thumble/<?=$val['gallery_image']?>" onclick="hitcounter('<?=$val[image_id]?>')"/></a>
```

This is just overview code for your hints.

Comment: my lightbox image will open a big image..<a onclick="counter(<?=$val[image_id]?>)" href="uploadedimage/gallery/big/<?=$val['gallery_image']?>" rel="lightbox[100,200]" title="<?=ucfirst($val['category_name'])?>" ><img src="uploadedimage/gallery/thumble/<?=$val['gallery_image']?>"/></a>....here onclick function not working

Comment: it works for first time but if again I click on image lightbox will show but hit counter not working

Comment: So only option is remain to hack in your lightbox library. You should add additional parameter in you <a>. For example <a class="hitcounter">. Now what you need to do this, when your lightbox is calling for popup, check your <A> object class is equal to "hitcounter". If it is then call ajax script that i mentioned previously.